# PYODBC: Can't iterate through SQL Query

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am trying to extract devices from SQL server and do the ping test of those devices.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
import subprocess
import pyodbc

data = {}


def list():
    conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};"
                          "Server=sqlserver;"
                          "Database=database;"
                          "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
       SELECT TOP 10 Names FROM sqldatabasetable
       ''')
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    for result in results:
        return result.Names
        #print(result.Names)
    conn.close()


def pingtest():
    response = subprocess.Popen(['ping.exe', list()], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    response = response.decode()
    if 'bytes=32' in response:
        status = 'Up'
        return status
    else:
        status = 'Down'
        return status

print(list())
print(pingtest())
#print(pingtest(), list())
```

When I print only `print(result.Names)` under the `list()` function, I get 10 devices, but when I return them to the `list()` and iterate those in `pingtest() function`, I get only the first device. I know I am missing something very obvious. And this should be a straight answer, but I'm not able to figure out exactly where should I loop through if I have to.

This prints the device names and ping status as:

```
['devicename1' , 'devicename2', 'devicename3', 'devicename4', 'devicename5']
Down
```

And I am expecting like this, going by how I have written the `print` commands:

```
devicename1
Ping status of devicename1
devicename2
Ping status of devicename2
and so on...
```

Comment: Kindly don't overwrite built-ins with your variables. `list` is a reserved keyword in Python.

Comment: @shad0w_wa1k3r My bad, I am using different function name, just edited when I posted on SO.

Comment: Oh okay, just advising since that can cause a lot of unnecessary, and sometimes hard to trace issues in the code.

Comment: Do you want to pass multiple device names to `ping.exe` or you want to run `ping.exe` multiple times with the various device names?

Comment: Thanks! I have just edited my question, the desired output and what output I am currently getting, If I am able to extract devices properly and run them like how I want in pingtest, I should be able to implement other functions in this code too, I am new to python and this my first time retrieving from a database and iterating through it

Comment: @shad0w_wa1k3r I would want to run ping.exe multiple times with the various device names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make `pingtest` accept a device_name parameter and pass to `ping.exe`. So, you could fetch your `list()` first and then iterate over that and pass each of the device to `pingtest` in that loop.

```
import subprocess
import pyodbc


data = {}


def mylist():
    conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};"
                          "Server=sqlserver;"
                          "Database=database;"
                          "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
       SELECT TOP 10 Names FROM sqldatabasetable
       ''')
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return [result.Names for result in results]


def pingtest(device):
    response = subprocess.Popen(['ping.exe', device], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    response = response.decode()
    if 'bytes=32' in response:
        status = 'Up'
        return status
    else:
        status = 'Down'
        return status


devices = mylist()
for device in devices:
    print(device)
    print(pingtest(device))
```

Comment: This seems to be working now, But we are getting the output as:
`['devicename1', 'devicename2', 'devicename3', 'devicename4', 'devicename5']
Up
Down
Up
Up
Down`

Comment: That's just some rearrangement of your `print` statements. Updated answer nonetheless.

Comment: Awesome! I have never used an argument inside the function before, And I will need to run similar function like `pingtest` for the rest of my code, do you suggest on doing the same for all of them? by creating argument inside the functions?

Comment: Yes, arguments are a key part of writing functions, because they make your function dynamic. Always try and use them where you feel your function could be a bit more generic, and thus, more reusable.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can utilize my weekend on completing the rest of my code now :) I will definitely read more on this.

Answer (score 3):

When you `print` in your `for result in results:` loop your code continues to iterate through each row retrieved. However, when you replace `print` with `return` then the first time through the loop the `return` will immediately exit the `list()` function and therefore you will only get the value from the first row.

If you want `list()` to return the values from all of the rows then you can replace your loop with a list comprehension like

```
return [result.Names for result in results]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, When I put it with a list comprehension like you mentioned, my `for result in results` prompts that local variable `result` is not used. Also, When I execute list() and pingtest() like this; `print(list(), pingtest())` prints all the device names in a list and prints only the ping status of last device. Do I need to change my for loop for pingtest() also?

Comment: @KaranM There's no loop under `pingtest` though. Also, you should `conn.close()` in the line above the `return` statement.

Comment: You're right! I edited `conn.close()` after I inserted the list comprehension tip from Gordon. But I really don;t know how should I loop through the `pingtest` as my data is getting extracted from a database, which itself is in a function

Comment: Thanks gordon, you helped me in the right direction, Shadow has completed the solution. :) Appreciate your time!